# Removing Rectangular Surfaces in 3D Matplotlib Helical Phase Plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, physics

I am trying to reproduce a 3D plot of a helical phase beam, similar to the image linked here[image] I have implemented the following code using Matplotlib and NumPy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


r = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
phi=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

R, PHI = np.meshgrid(r, phi)

X, Y = R*np.cos(PHI), R*np.sin(PHI)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,10),subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))


l_values=[0,1,2,3]
index_values = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
for l ,index in zip(l_values , index_values):
    Z = (l*PHI)%(2*np.pi)
    surface = ax[index[0],index[1]].plot_surface(Z, Y, X, alpha=1,linewidth=0.5,edgecolors='black',color='red')
    #ax[index[0],index[1]].plot_wireframe(Z, Y, X, alpha=1,color='red')
    ax[index[0],index[1]].set_aspect('equalyz')


plt.show()
```

[image]
However, the resulting plot has rectangular surfaces linking the back of the spiral to the front, as shown here. How can I modify the code to remove these rectangular surfaces and achieve a cleaner helical phase plot?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on improving the plot. Thank you!

Comment: See [ask]. Research enough. You specified that rectangular surfaces. For example, the ```Z[-1, :]``` is equal to the ```Z[0, :]``` for l = 1.

Comment: @relent95 I don't agree with that comment. In my view the OP nicely presented the question; they provided a reference picture of what they're aiming for and a complete working example of their current attempt. I was able to copy the code and produce an answer from it.

Comment: @user3128, you don't understand my previous comment. Replace the ```Z = (l*PHI)%(2*np.pi)``` with ```Z = (l*PHI)``` in the OP's code. It's not specifying that rectangular surfaces. For example, ```Z[-1, :]``` is not equal to the ```Z[0, :]``` for l = 1.

Comment: @relent95 I felt the "Research enough" and "How to ask" wasn't right for a well-presented question where they've made a solid attempt.

Comment: @user3128, preliminary researching includes preliminary debugging. This question is like asking why ```[e % 3 for e in [0,1,2,3]]``` ends with zero. The OP and you didn't try to examine the input data of the ```plot_surface()``` API. The API simply worked as expected.

Comment: The `%` fix for the input data was included my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate the desired results by adapting your code.

I couldn't get the last one looking as clear as your reference picture. There are ways to use a custom light source and custom colour shading to bring out the topology of a surface - example at: [How to replicate mathematica's 3d plot look with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77631267/how-to-replicate-mathematicas-3d-plot-look-with-matplotlib/77631652#77631652).

You could try running `%matplotlib widget` (in VSCode) to enable interactive panning on 3D plots, and use that to find the best viewing angle. Alternatively, adjust the angles in `ax.view_init(...)`.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

r = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 20)

R, PHI = np.meshgrid(r, phi)
X = R * np.cos(PHI)
Y = R * np.sin(PHI)

colors = ['tab:cyan', 'tab:red', 'tab:green', 'tab:orange', 'tab:red']
edge_props = {'linewidth': 0.5, 'edgecolors': 'black'}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 12), subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

#
# Plot separate discs
#
ax = axes[0]
ax.view_init(azim=-65, elev=35, roll=0)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('PHI')

#Select a position along z for each disc
z_vals = [0, 1, 2]

for z in z_vals:
    ax.plot_surface(
        X, Y, np.full(Y.shape, z),
        alpha=0.8, color=colors[z_vals.index(z)],
        **edge_props
    )

#
# Plot a twister
#
ax = axes[1]
ax.view_init(azim=-65, elev=35, roll=0)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('PHI')

Z = PHI
ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z,
    alpha=1, color=colors[-1], **edge_props
)
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=None, zoom=0.9)

#Optional arrows
ax.quiver(
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, Z.max() * 1.3,
    color='black', alpha=1, linewidth=4,
    arrow_length_ratio=0.2,
)
ax.quiver(
    0, 0, 0,
    X.max() * 1.1, 0, 0,
    color='black', alpha=1, linewidth=4,
    arrow_length_ratio=0.2,
)

#
# Plot multiple twisters
#
ax = axes[2]
ax.view_init(azim=0, elev=-40, roll=-90)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('PHI')

#Radian offset of each twister
phi0_per_twister = [0, 90 * np.pi / 180]

Z = PHI
for index, phi0 in enumerate(phi0_per_twister):
    ax.plot_surface(
        R * np.cos(PHI + phi0), R * np.sin(PHI + phi0), Z,
        alpha=[0.4, 1][index], color=colors[index], **edge_props
    )

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=None, zoom=0.9)
    
plt.show()
```