# How to replicate mathematica's 3d plot look with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to replicate the plot below done in mathematica using matplotlib in python. As you can see, it is very clean and you immediately know what you're looking at.

[image]

This is the python code to generate the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import butter
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

# Butterworth filter order
order = 5

# Create a meshgrid for sigma and omega
sigma = np.linspace(-1.5, 0.5, 400)
omega = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 400)
sigma, omega = np.meshgrid(sigma, omega)

# Complex frequency (s = sigma + j*omega)
s = sigma + 1j * omega

# Butterworth filter (analog, so we use s-domain)
b, a = butter(order, 1, analog=True)
w, h = s, np.polyval(b, s) / np.polyval(a, s)

# Calculate the magnitude of the frequency response
response = np.abs(h)
response[response > 40] = 40

# 3D Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(sigma, omega, response, cmap=cm.viridis)

ax.set_zlim(0, 40)
ax.set_xlabel('Sigma')
ax.set_ylabel('Omega')
ax.set_zlabel('Magnitude')

plt.show()
```

It looks way less nicer:

[image]

Comment: What do you like to change in your plot exactly? The angle of view, the transparency of the panes, height or mesh?

Comment: The shading so that it is easy to see where exactly the hills start to rise.

Comment: I am pretty sure you should use a solid color instead of `cmap`, such as `color='orange'` and then the shadings will be applied automatically. In fact, `shade=True` is the default setting.

Answer (score 3):

Here I generated some data to show how it works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(0, 9.42, 500)
Y = np.linspace(0, 9.42, 500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = -np.sqrt(np.sin(X)**2 + np.cos(Y + X)**2) + X**2/30

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, antialiased=False, rstride=5, cstride=5, color='#00c0e7')

ax.view_init(45, 80)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is your code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import butter
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

# Butterworth filter order
order = 5

# Create a meshgrid for sigma and omega
sigma = np.linspace(-1.5, 0.5, 400)
omega = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 400)
sigma, omega = np.meshgrid(sigma, omega)

# Complex frequency (s = sigma + j*omega)
s = sigma + 1j * omega

# Butterworth filter (analog, so we use s-domain)
b, a = butter(order, 1, analog=True)
w, h = s, np.polyval(b, s) / np.polyval(a, s)

# Calculate the magnitude of the frequency response
response = np.abs(h)
response[response > 40] = 40

# 3D Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(sigma, omega, response, color='#ff7300', antialiased=False, rstride=1, cstride=1)

ax.set_zlim(0, 40)
ax.set_xlabel('Sigma')
ax.set_ylabel('Omega')
ax.set_zlabel('Magnitude')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't look as good as the mathematica one.

Comment: I suggest changing other factors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that takes on some of the desired aesthetic.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource

# 3D Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(azim=-50, elev=30, roll=0)

downsample = 1

lightsource = LightSource(azdeg=50, altdeg=10)

#Overlay same plot to help mitigate antialiasing artifacts
for _ in range(3):
    surf = ax.plot_surface(
        sigma, omega, response, antialiased=True,
        color='tab:orange',
        lightsource=lightsource,
        linewidth=0, alpha=1,
        rstride=downsample, cstride=downsample,
    )

# #Alternative using trisurf
# for _ in range(3):
#     surf = ax.plot_trisurf(
#         sigma.ravel()[::downsample],
#         omega.ravel()[::downsample],
#         response.ravel()[::downsample],
#         color='tab:orange', antialiased=True,
#         lightsource=lightsource,
#         linewidth=0,
#     )

for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis, ax.zaxis]:
    axis.pane.fill = False
    axis.pane.set_edgecolor('black')
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_xlabel('σ', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('ω', fontsize=12)
ax.set_zlabel('|f(σ, ω)|', fontsize=12)
ax.set_title('Butterworth frequency response')
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=None, zoom=0.9)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one looks wrong.

Comment: I've now updated my answer.